# getObjectInfo RecordTypeInfos wrong value issue in Experience cloud

Tags: lightning-web-components, getobjectinfo

When using the getObjectInfo Method in a LWC i get two different recordType names when running the Component in Salesforce or in the Experience cloud:

```
import { getObjectInfo} from "lightning/uiObjectInfoApi";
```

in Salesforce:
[image: in Salesforce:]
in Experience cloud:
[image: in Experience cloud:]
There is a "t" to much. I suspect the RecordType has been renamed after a typo. But the Experience Cloud doesn't take the current value. (Tested in Anonymus mode and still the wrong value is shown)

A query also shows the expected value:
[image: query]

Does anybody have an Idea why this occurs and how to fix it?

(I'm not asking for a workaround. I know other ways to get the recordTypeId i was just wondering why this is happening.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the Translation into German "Plattform" is the Problem.My caching Problem was actually in SF so they showed me the English value even though the method return the translated value. Since getObjectInfo doesn't have a DeveloperName field for RecordType I'll use apex and the RecordType DeveloperName Field.